# Why is the rotated image the same aspect ratio?

Tags: php, gd

I'm using some PHP code from jquery file upload and I'm trying to rotate an image prior to saving it.  Below is my function call:

```
public function CreateThumb($file_name, $options){

    $file_path = $options['src_dir'].$file_name;
    $new_file_path = $options['dst_dir'].$file_name;

    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);

    if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
        return false;
    }
    $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
            $options['max_height'] / $img_height
    );

    $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
    $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
    $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
            $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
            $options['jpeg_quality'] : 95;
            break;
        case 'gif':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagegif';
            $image_quality = null;
            break;
        case 'png':
            @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
            @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
            @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagepng';
            $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
            $options['png_quality'] : 9;
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = null;
    }

    $src_img = imagerotate($src_img, 90, 0) ;

    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
            $new_img,
            $src_img,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $img_width,
            $img_height
    ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);

    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($src_img);
    @imagedestroy($new_img);

    return $success;
}
```

The image gets rotated but it still maintains it's original aspect ratio and is cropping the photo.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in how you set the new values:

```
$new_width = $img_width * $scale;
$new_height = $img_height * $scale;
```

Should be, in case of a 90 degrees rotation:

```
$new_width = $img_height * $scale;    // reverse height and width
$new_height = $img_width * $scale;    // reverse height and width
```

**Edit:** And as the original image is rotated, the old width and height have to be reversed:

```
$success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_height,    // reverse width and height
        $img_width      // reverse width and height
) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
```

Comment: @Paul After you rotate your source image, you also need to switch the width and height of the source image in your success function as the new width is the old height, etc.

Comment: Thanks jeroen! That worked for 90 degrees but in the case of 180 I need to reverse them yet again...

Comment: @Paul In case of 180 degrees, the dimensions don't change except for the scaling...

Comment: good point, so basically for 90 or 270 I can reverse them and in the case of 180 I don't.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Paul If you put your rotation at the start, before your width and height calculation, the numbers will automatically be correct as you are using the dimensions of the rotated image so you don't have to worry about reversing any more no matter how much you rotate. Using your original code.

Comment: I actually gave that a try in the beginning but the rotate requires an image resource and the getimagesize can only accept a file name so this would require me to rotate, save, scale, and save.  I think I'll be forced to use one of the two width/height calculations based on the angle chosen.

Comment: @Paul Yes, you'd probably have to move some stuff around and do the `switch` statement twice so perhaps it's not the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: if you are going to use that many @'s to ignore errors, you might as well just put `error_reporting(0);` at the start of the code.

Secondly, the reason that I saw for the lack of change in pixel ratio is because your `$scale` is backwards. You have it saying `scale = Whole/Part` which will almost always give you a value greater than 1 (increasing pixel ratio) unless the max size is smaller than the image size. You'll want it to be `scale = Part/Whole` So its a decimal ratio (ie 100px/400px, scale = .25).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  My scale works correctly but the issue is that the rotated image still has the original aspect ratio.